# Insert new Nginx conf in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am migrating to Elastic Beanstalk and was not able to make changes to the nginx file, or even increment a new file. All configurations per AWS documentation did not work. So I did it as follows:

/.ebextesions -> 01_laravel_nginx.config:

```
files:
   "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/laravel.conf":
     mode: "000644"
     owner: root
     group: root
     content: |
       location / {
         try_files $ uri $ uri / /index.php?$query_string;
         gzip_static on;
       }
```

/.ebextesions -> 02_install_nginx.config:

```
container_commands:
   01_runmyshellscript:
     command: "sudo ln -s /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/laravel.conf /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk"
```

After performing this configuration, the same information as in the /var/proxy/staging/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk directory will be in the /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk directory.

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just trying to add one more conf, instead of changing what already existed by default. I tried to perform this configuration as follows:

```
.platform / nginx / conf.d / laraval.conf
```

But I didn't create. have to create all the files?

```
.platform / nginx / conf.d / laraval.conf
.platform / nginx / nginx.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to setup nginx on EB environments using **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2) is through `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html). Or if you want to fully overwrite the main `nginx.conf` you should provide its custom version using `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`.